# How to get form field values in form and send mail

Tags: django, forms, web-applications, view, django-class-based-views

Django version 2.2

I have a form as below  in forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    email_address = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email Address', max_length=100)
```

in form.html

```
<form  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    model = Test
    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
        form = NameForm(request.POST)  # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass

            email_address = form.cleaned_data['email_address']
            print (email_address)
            if (email_address == Test.email_address):

                return HttpResponseRedirect('../success') # Redirect after POST
            else :
                return HttpResponseRedirect('../failed')
    else:
        form = NameForm()  # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model)
email_address= models.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

All the respective modules are successfully imported , and the form get submitted without any problems .

What i need to do is , when a user provide an email address using the form, email address have to be checked with the emails in the database(models.py) which is provided before . After checking with the emailaddresses in the database , if provided emailaddress matches the emailid in the database , email have to be sent to the email id . The logic is simple, but accessing and using the form.field values in class view form has failed .

I have tried the below code ,

```
testmail = form.cleaned_data['email_address']
if (testmaill == 'mymail@database.com' ): 
  return HttpResponseRedirect('../success')
```

And it didn't work

Comment: Please specify the actual error, what are you getting?

Comment: @Alasdair  i tried using the form.cleaned_data , it didn't worked , i tried 
testmail = form.cleaned_data['email_address']
if (testmaill == 'mymail@database.com' ):
   return HttpResponseRedirect('../success')

but it didn't redirect to /success when i used the same mail id in the database as form input, 

@-Akhilendra i am not getting any errors , I can't process the requirement ... 
I tried function view for form , still i cant access the form.filed value

Comment: i have done that printing , it is not showing in the rendered webpage

Comment: thanks @Alasdair , got it in the console , but I am not able to validate the email i provide with emails in the database

Comment: Can you please check the code again , I have edited and converted it into function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the validation in your form. See more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/.

Example:

```
def clean_email_address(self):
        email_address = self.cleaned_data.get('email_address')
        if Test.objects.filter(email_address__iexact=email_address).count() == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your email address not exist")

        return email_address
```

And then in your view if the form is valid, you can get an email address:

```
 form.cleaned_data.get("email_address")
```

You can also see which data was provided.

```
form.data.get("email_address")
```

Here is your edited function:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
        form = NameForm(request.POST)  # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass

            email_address = form.cleaned_data.get('email_address')
            if Test.objects.filter(email_address__iexact=email_address).count() == 0:

                return HttpResponseRedirect('../success') # Redirect after POST
            else :
                return HttpResponseRedirect('../failed')
    else:
        form = NameForm()  # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: For iterate all emails from your database, you can use. `for e in Test.objects.all():
    print(e.email_address)`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: i dont want to print the email_address , i want to check it with the email id i provide via forms , can I use httpresponseredirect instead of ValidationError

Comment: Yes, you can do it in views. I edited your function in my answer.

Comment: It's really helpful , got what i needed